putting implementation details in a separate provisional just in case needed
Strategy:
File Provisional A with just enough details to enable invention.
File Provisional B, within 12 months, with much more implementation details that guarantee enablement of invention.
File non-provisional within 12 months of Provisional A, claiming Provisional A's priority date only. If examiner determines that Provisional A is not sufficient to enable invention, only then claim Provisional B.
Is this strategy allowed?

No.  A claim of priority has a time limit -
From the MPEP

reference must also be submitted within the later of four months from the actual filing date of the later-filed application or sixteen months from the filing date of the prior-filed provisional application.

In the case of unintentional delay - not your case - one can petition the director to allow a late priority claim.
Also, examiners rarely issue rejections for lack of enablement in “predicable” arts unless it is cure-all or perpetual motion machine. It is more of an issue in court where expert witnesses may testify as to the ability of a person of ordinary skill in the art could product the invention without undue experimentation.
